# delete a note from localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am using this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJXmpZ but I am struggling to implement a new delete button for each note.

I have added this in my html:

```
<input id="delNote" value=" delete note" type="button" />
```

And I added this function to the script

```
function deleteNote(note) {
    localStorage.removeItem(note);
}
```

However, seems like I'm doing something wrong, the delete button is unresponsive.

Any help is highly appreciated.

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJXmpZ)

Comment: The codepen works for me.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, I'm saying that it has no method for deleting a single note, just emptying the localStorage. I am trying to implement that method.

Comment: Then you should update your codepen to include the button you're saying doesn't work

Comment: Check the codepen, it's updated.

Comment: You're not sending a note to the delete function, only the event is getting passed.

Comment: You can't have more than one element with the same `id`. Use classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

the first thing that sticks out is that you are never actually calling the function when you click it.

Comment: I taught I am calling it using 
     $(document).on('click', '#delNote', deleteNote);

Answer (score 0):

Call the delete function like this:
`<input id="delNote" value=" delete note" type="button" onClick="deleteNote(XXXX);"/>`

where XXXX is your note, or however you are referring your note (I am guessing with some sort of ID)

Answer (score 0):

You are

```
localStorage.setItem('note_'+note.length, note);
```

note.length being the input form length not a unique variable and not sequential.

Type localStorage in the console.log in developer tools to view what is in localStorage.

And attempting to remove with

```
localStorage.removeItem(note); // note is an object object not a key.
```

**note** is not the key **'note_'+note.length** is.

Each time two notes have the same length the last note removes/replaces the first note and you don't have a list of keys to reference which note you want to delete. I would suggest setting or creating a key index by counting each time a note is created and using the count as your key.

```
localStorage.count
```

Then you can add to

```
if (localStorage.count) {
   localStorage.count = localStorage.count+1
   } else {
   localstorage.count = 1; // no notes begin at 1.
   }
localStorage.setItem('note_'+localStorage.count, note);
```

and remove the last note

```
if (localStorage.count) {
   localStorage.removeItem('note_'+localStorage.count);
   localStorage.count = localStorage.count-1
   } else {
      // no notes localStorage count is zero or undefined? same difference here.
   }
```

You will also need to update the display loop as it displays all localStorage as a note.

Or you could use localStorage.length,

```
localStorage.setItem('note_'+localStorage.length, note);
```

and

```
localStorage.removeItem('note_'+localStorage.length);
```

But if anything other than a note is placed in localStorage the logic of the assumption breaks deleteNote(localStorage.length)

Either way you could place an X in the top right corner of the note to call deleteNote(key), but still need to update the display loop.

Thus.

```
function deleteNote(note) {
        localStorage.removeItem(note);
    }
```

is called from the X with:

```
deleteNote(key);
```